# How to export data to string from datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm tried to export datagrid data to string in c# wpf. how could I do it?

I've tried some codes, show them now

```
string stOutput = "";
// Export titles:
string sHeaders = "";

for (int j = 0; j < Equipment_Request.Columns.Count; j++)
    sHeaders = sHeaders.ToString() +  
        Convert.ToString(Equipment_Request.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t";
stOutput += sHeaders + "\r\n";

// Export data.
for (int i = 0; i < Equipment_Request.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    string stLine = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < Equipment_Request.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
        stLine = stLine.ToString() +  
           Convert.ToString(Equipment_Request.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
    stOutput += stLine + "\r\n";
}
```

It's show's me red line when i tried to get the specified value in for.

hope you could help me soon and thanks

Comment: You have not just a _red line_ you have an error and a message is displayed on the error list window. Please tell us what error do you see.

Comment: 'Data Grid' does not contain definition for 'Rows' and no accessible extension method for 'Rows'... its what it write for me

Comment: Why don't you get the ItemSource and export whatever you have set into the ItemSource?

Comment: How could I do it? can you explain?

Comment: How do you set the content of the DataGrid? (Binding) Are you using some kind of list? Are you using a DataTable? In any case ItemSource is a reference to the data  you have used to populate the grid.

Comment: I using ItemSource to add Products to table. 
Code:
 
var data = new ProductR { ID = counter.ToString(), Product = box_product_r.Text,        Unit = box_Unit_r.Text, Amount = box_Amount_r.Text };
                    Equipment_Request.Items.Add(data);

public class ProductR
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public string Amount { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, then every single item in your DataGrid is a Product element and you can retrieve it from the ItemsSource property.

You can rewrite your logic in this way

```
string headers = "";
List<string> data = new List<string>();

headers = string.Join("\t", Equipment_Request.Columns.Select(x => x.HeaderText));

foreach(ProductR p in Equipment_Request.ItemsSource)
{
    data.Add(p.ToString());
}
string output = headers + "r\n" + string.Join(data, "\r\n");
```

As you can see this is a lot simpler to understand. We store the information in a list of strings and then we join the individual elements to a single string with the required separator. This also remove the final tab present in your strings and not followed by an actual value to export.

Another key change is the override for the ToString method that you need to add to your  Product class. The override helps in creating a string representation of a single product instance, for example

```
public class ProductR
{

     .....

     public override string ToString()
     {
         return this.ID + "\t" + 
                this.Product + "\t" + 
                this.Unit + "\t" + 
                this.Amount;
     }
}
```